# Plot Data with MultiIndex from pd.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot, seaborn

I import data from 3 different dataframes (all with the same keys) and put it together to 1 single dataframe.

```
df1 = read_xlsx('Means_Cent')
df2 = read_xlsx('Means_Rand')
df3 = read_xlsx('Means_Const')
df1['Key'] = 'Cent'
df2['Key'] = 'Rand'
df3['Key'] = 'Const'

df_means = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3], keys = ['Cent', 'Rand', 'Const'])
```

Now i want to create a plot using DataFrame.plot() where I have 1 graph for every key = ['Cent', 'Rand', 'Const'] in the same figure.

Part of my dataframe df_means looks like this:

```
         02_VOI  03_Solidity  04_Total_Cells
Cent  0   1.430       19.470           132.0
      1   1.415       18.880           131.0
      2   1.460       19.695           135.0
      3   1.520       19.695           141.0
Rand  0   1.430       19.205           132.0
      1   1.430       19.170           132.0
      2   1.445       19.430           133.5
      3   1.560       19.820           144.5
Const 0   1.175       22.695           108.5
      1   1.430       22.260           132.0
      2   1.180       21.090           109.0
      3   1.360       22.145           126.0
```

Now I want to plot 02_VOI vs 04_Total_Cells, and it should be 1 graph for each key ( g1 = 02_VOI(Cent) vs 04_Total_Cells(Cent), g2 = 02_VOI(Rand) vs 04_Total_Cells(Rand) ...)

I tried it using DataFrame.unstack():

```
df_means.unstack(level = 0).plot(x = '02_VOI', y = '04_Total_Cells')
```

but this seems to mess up the keys. It returns 9 graphs (1 for each combination of VOI(Cent,Rand,Const) vs Total_Cells(Cent,Rand,Const).

Thanks for your help, I'm also happy for tips on how to better connect the 3 initial dataframes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I would use Seaborn plots for this. It is much easier. Seaborn likes ["tidy"](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v059i10/v59i10.pdf) data.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
df_mean = pd.read_clipboard()
df_mean
```

Output:

```
         02_VOI  03_Solidity  04_Total_Cells
Cent  0   1.430       19.470           132.0
      1   1.415       18.880           131.0
      2   1.460       19.695           135.0
      3   1.520       19.695           141.0
Rand  0   1.430       19.205           132.0
      1   1.430       19.170           132.0
      2   1.445       19.430           133.5
      3   1.560       19.820           144.5
Const 0   1.175       22.695           108.5
      1   1.430       22.260           132.0
      2   1.180       21.090           109.0
      3   1.360       22.145           126.0
```

Reset index and rename columns as you wish.

```
df_mean = df_mean.reset_index()
df_mean = df_mean.rename(columns={'level_0':'Groups','level_1':'Samples'})
_ = sns.lmplot(x='02_VOI',y='04_Total_Cells', data=df_mean, scatter=True, col='Groups',fit_reg=False)
```

[image]